# ListPagination for local array data in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am fetching the contact data from `PhoneGap` and displaying into the `Sencha Touch` listview. I am using `ListPagination` plugin to load the data when the scrollbar reaches to end.

But the issue is `ListPagination` only works with remote data and hence `pageSize` property works in that case.

But here i am storing the data of `PhoneGap` into an array and loading it using 
`Ext.getStore('ContactStore').setData(arr)`.

So is there any way in `Sencha Touch` to perform pagination locally using `ListPagination` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the `load` method of the store, calling its `setData()` only with a subset of the entire array.

In your derived store class:

```
Ext.define('App.store.XXX', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        storeId: 'xxx',
        mypage: 0,              // use this as 'cursor' in your array
        pageSize: 10,              
        model: 'App.model.XXX',
        ...
    },
    load: function() {
        this.mypage += 1;
        // maybe add some sanity check on array dimension
        this.setData(Ext.Array.slice(arr, 0, this.mypage*this.getPageSize()));
    }
});
```

I've not test the code above. Get it as an 'idea' of resolution.

Comment: can you give me some example ?

Comment: I've just added an example of the idea

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution to get a paged list from an array in Sencha Touch 2.4.
The trick is to hook in the beforeload - Event of the store and set the peace of data from an array.

Here you find the code: http://www.soft4tec.de/development/sencha-touch/list-paging-with-array-store.html